# Receiving the Right Data from YouTube Data API

Tags: python, youtube-data-api

First time I've ever used python. I am trying to get the metadata of Alex Jones Channel between these dates, but I am unsure how to only get the title and the statistics. I tried to change the `part=` section of the api query, but am getting an error. If anyone has any suggestions it would be greatly appreciated. I have been having a hard time understanding the YouTube Data API docs. I took out my API key due to obvious reasons for this post.

```
import requests
import json


key = '*MYAPIKEY*'
channel_id = 'UCvsye7V9psc-APX6wV1twLg'
published_after = '2015-01-01T03:00:00-05:00'
published_before = '2018-05-04T03:00:00-04:00'

http_endpoint = ("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&maxResults=50&publishedAfter="+published_after+"&publishedBefore="+published_before+"&channelId="+channel_id+"&order=date&key="+key)

response = requests.get(http_endpoint)
response_json = response.json()

nextPageToken = response_json.get("nextPageToken")

while nextPageToken:
    response = requests.get("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&maxResults=50&publishedAfter="+published_after+"&publishedBefore="+published_before+"&channelId="+channel_id+"&order=date&key="+key+"&pageToken="+nextPageToken)
    response_json = response.json()
    nextPageToken = response_json.get("nextPageToken")

with open('data.json', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(response_json, outfile)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have only the statistics by adding the field "&fields=items%2Fsnippet%2Ftitle" in your youtube request.

But the search.list function doesn't return statistics.
To get videos statistics you have to use the function video.list. You will have to  pass the videos ids as a argument to this function.

Comment: Would you recommend that I filter out the video_ids from my current search then run a loop that makes an API call for each videos information?

Comment: Yes, it's the only way to get statistics and some other details about videos too